# Karate framework using IntelliJ : Undefined Step Reference in feature file but working from command line

Tags: karate, cucumber-java

I have setup Karate framework by creating Maven project using archetype. Everything went fine and I am able to run the tests from command line. All good all well here. Now the question, though I am having Cucumber for Java plugin installed and enabled, I am getting issue saying that "Undefined Step Reference" in feature file and also not able to trigger the scenario from feature file. Below is the screenshot.
[image]

Really I am not understanding how its working from commandline but not from feature file. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is not Cucumber. There is a specific plugin for [Karate in IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate) which give you a better experience to develop and run tests from within the IDE.

But Karate is designed to work on the CLI / command-line, this is how teams can run tests smoothly in CI / CD.

Comment: Thanks Peter for making it clear! After installing this plugin, the error has gone and it looks like running tests from feature file has been moved to PLUS subscription.